# What is the purpose to make a function which return a function?

Tags: swift

I was reading Apple doc [about swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1) .
it has an example in which it made a function which returns a function

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

So here my concern is what are advantages of this practice and when to use it?

and if some one can also help me with concept of "A function can take another function as one of its arguments." than that will be so kind

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Functions are a first-class type. This means that a function can return another function as its value._ Above example is leading you to `Closures` and acting as a bridge between the concept of `Functions` & `Closures`.

Comment: @Mr.Bista thanks for your comment dude, can you please more explane with some refrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a really common case of this that you use all the time, probably without even realizing it.

Instance methods are really just class methods that return closures.

Take `String.hasPrefix` for example, which has type `(String) -> (String) -> Bool`.

So `String.hasPrefix` takes `String` argument, which is the instance the instance method will act upon, and returns a closure of type `(String) -> Bool`.

We would usually get this closure by using a form like `"The quick brown fox".hasPrefix`, but we can also use String.hasPrefix("The quick brown fox"), which is equivalent.

The result of these expressions is the `hasPrefix` function, bound to the specific instance (the String `"The quick brown fox"`) that it will act upon.

We can then invoke this closure with another String argument, which tells it what prefix to look for.

Here's what you might typically write:

```
let result = "The quick brown fox".hasPrefix("The") // => True
```

Let's break that down into steps (with type annotations added for emphasis on the types at play):

```
import Foundation

let instance: String = "The quick brown fox"
let desiredPrefx: String = "The"

let staticMethod: (String) -> (String) -> Bool = String.hasPrefix
let boundInstanceMethod: (String) -> Bool = staticMethod(instance)
let result: Bool = boundInstanceMethod(desiredPrefx) // => true
```

equivalent:

```
import Foundation

let instance: String = "The quick brown fox"
let desiredPrefx: String = "The"

let boundInstanceMethod: (String) -> (String) -> Bool = instance.hasPrefix
let result: Bool = boundInstanceMethod(desiredPrefx) // => true
```

Comment: very explanatory!

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of creating a function that returns a function is that the inner function remembers the environment that it was created in.  Typically, when you call a function, the variables within that function end when the function finishes.  By returning a function, however, you create what is called a closure, and this allows you to hold on to the environment that the closure was created in, so you can use it over and over again.

There are many benefits to being able to accept a function as a parameter to another function.  For example, you could create a filter function that accepts an array as its first argument and another function as its second.  Then, you could call your filter function and pass it a function that would check each element of the array to see if it was even, and return a new array that only contains even values.  You could also call the same filter function with a function that checks each element of an array to see if it is odd, and return a new array containing only odd numbers.  This makes the filter function far more flexible than it would otherwise be, and allows you to get away with writing less code.  Instead of writing a new, complex function every time you want to filter the elements of an array, and having to maintain a potential multitude of filter functions, you only have to write one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it would be more generous if you can explan with example

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know Swift well enough to give you one, but know you know what your own example is doing conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

`makeIncrementer()` have a function `addOne(number: Int)`
That is only eccessable with in `makeIncrementer()`
Out side of `makeIncrementer()` we can not access `addOne(number: Int)`.